# Putting a Bitmap into a Bundle

Tags: android, bitmap, bundle, parcelable, parcel

I want to pass a String and a Bitmap to a Service using AIDL. The Service implements this AIDL method:

```
void addButton(in Bundle data);
```

In my case, the Bundle contains a String and a Bitmap.

The calling application (client) has this code:

```
...
// Add text to the bundle
Bundle data = new Bundle();
String text = "Some text";
data.putString("BundleText", text);

// Add bitmap to the bundle
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myIcon);
data.putParcelable("BundleIcon", icon);

try {
    myService.addButton(data);

} catch (RemoteException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

On the service end, I have a ButtonComponent class with this code:

```
public final class ButtonComponent implements Parcelable {
    private final Bundle mData;

    private ComponComponent(Parcel source) {
        mData = source.readBundle();
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mData.getString("BundleText");
    }

    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        Bitmap icon = (Bitmap) mData.getParcelable("BundleIcon");
        return icon;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel aOutParcel, int aFlags) {
        aOutParcel.writeBundle(mData);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

After creating a ButtonComponent, the Service creates a button using the text and icon from the ButtonComponent object:

```
...
mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_button, aParent, true);
Button button = (Button) aParent.getChildAt(aParent.getChildCount() - 1);

// Set caption and icon
String caption = buttonComponent.getText();
if (caption != null) {
    button.setText(caption);
}

Bitmap icon = buttonComponent.getIcon();
if (icon != null) {
    BitmapDrawable iconDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(icon);
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconDrawable, null, null, null);
}
...
```

As a result, the button is displayed with the correct text and I can see the space for the icon, but the actual bitmap is not drawn (i.e. there's an empty space on the left side of the text).

Is it correct to put a Bitmap into a Bundle in this way?

If I should use a Parcel (vs a Bundle) is there any way to maintain a single 'data' argument in the AIDL method to keep text and icon together?

Side question: How do I decide to use Bundles vs Parcels?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Problem was that the PNG I was using is not supported by Android.
The code:

```
icon.getConfig()
```

returns null.

Answer (score 3):

Here is answer for your second question.

Source : http://www.anddev.org/general-f3/bundle-vs-parcel-vs-message-t517.html

> A Bundle is functionally equivalent to a standard Map. The reason we
>   didn't just use a Map is because in the contexts where Bundle is used,
>   the only things that are legal to put into it are primitives like
>   Strings, ints, and so on. Because the standard Map API lets you insert
>   arbitrary Objects, this would allow developers to put data into the
>   Map that the system can't actually support, which would lead to weird,
>   non-intuitive application errors. Bundle was created to replace Map
>   with a typesafe container that makes it explicitly clear that it only
>   supports primitives.
>
> A Parcel is similar to a Bundle, but is more sophisticated and can
>   support more complex serialization of classes. Applications can
>   implement the Parcelable interface to define application-specific
>   classes that can be passed around, particularly when using Services.
>   Parcelables can be more sophisticated than Bundles, but this comes at
>   a cost of significantly higher overhead.
>
> Bundle and Parcel are both data serialization mechanisms, and for the
>   most part both are used when application code is passing data across
>   processes. However, because Parcel is much higher overhead that
>   Bundle, Bundles are used in the more common places like the onCreate
>   method, where overhead must be as low as possible. Parcels are most
>   commonly used to allow applications to define Services with logical
>   APIs that can use application-meaningful classes as method arguments
>   and return values. If we required Bundle there, it would result in
>   really clunky APIs. You should in general still keep your Service APIs
>   as simple as possible, because primitives will serialize more
>   efficiently than custom Parcelable classes.

Answer (score 1):

While gt_ebuddy gives a nice answer, I just have a little side note to your question:

Problem: You are trying to pass a `Bitmap` object to memory, it can be fine; however, it's absolutely not good to pass many `Bitmap` objects like this. Really bad practice.

My Solution: The image is already existed in `resources`, it has an unique `ID`; make use out of it. Instead of trying to pass a lot of heavy `Bitmaps`, you can pass its `ID` using `Bundle` or `Parcel`, but `Bundle` is preferable for simple data structure.

Comment: Thank you. In my scenario bitmaps are ~900 bytes, which is probably a fair size, and I want to avoid including all of them in the service's APK (there could be many different clients). If I used a unique ID, I guess both clients' and service's packages will contain the actual PNG... right?

Comment: all of your images should be contained in `/res/drawable` directory